# Алгоритм Тарьяна для топологической сортировки: что за двуличность?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

я просматриваю разные алгоритмы, в том числе - есть красивая задачка про **топологическую сортировку**:

дан ориентированный граф, то есть, набор вершин, соединенных стрелочками. Можно ли так занумеровать вершины, чтобы любая стрелочка вела от числа с меньшим номером к числу с бОльшим номером?

Пример:

[image: граф с нумерацией]

Понятно, что это должен быть граф без циклов.

И я легко нагуглил, что такой алгоритм поиска [тополологической сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) называется "алгоритмом Тарьяна"

А дальше начинается мистика.

Во [многих](http://algolist.manual.ru/sort/top_sort.php) [местах](https://habr.com/ru/post/104772/) алгоритм Тарьяна и даже задача, которую он решает, сформулированы совершенно иначе: "Алгоритм Тарьяна для поиска LCA оффлайн (ближайшего общего предка (least common ancestor, LCA))"

я понимаю, что есть, видимо, какой то красивый переход от одной формулировки задачи к другой, но не могу найти, что это за переход? И есть ли объяснение алгоритма Тарьяна именно для топологической сортировки?

В коменатриях мне подсказали, что, веротяно, у Тарьяна два совершенно разных "именных" и не связанных по смыслу друг с другом алгоритма. Так ли это?

**Дополнение:**

я нашел [сравнительно понятную](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) статью, (на которую мне указал и Станислав Володарский в комментариях)

Потом я переписал в VSC программу, на которую приведена ссылка вниуз статьи.

При этом я взял граф, приведенный в статье в "Пример работы алгоритма", и заменил буквы в названиях вершин на числа от 1 до 5. И ввел туда 8 рёбер.

Результат работы программы - парадоксальный: она выдала `0 1 3 5 4 2`. А теперь, внимание, вопрос: **а что же это такое?**

Программа:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <conio.h>

    using namespace std;

    int n=5; // число вершин
    vector<int> g[8]; // граф
    bool used[8];
    vector<int> ans;
     
    void dfs (int v) {
        used[v] = true;
        for (size_t i=0; i<g[v].size(); ++i) {
            int to = g[v][i];
            if (!used[to])
                dfs (to);
        }
        ans.push_back (v);
    }
     
    void topological_sort() {
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            used[i] = false;
        ans.clear();
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            if (!used[i])
                dfs (i);
        reverse (ans.begin(), ans.end());
    }

    int main(){
        g[0] = {1, 2};
        g[1] = {1, 3};
        g[2] = {1, 4};
        g[3] = {1, 5};
        g[4] = {2, 4};
        g[5] = {3, 4};
        g[6] = {3, 5};
        g[7] = {4, 5};
        topological_sort();
        for( size_t i=0; i<ans.size(); ++i )
            cout << ans[i] << " ";
        getch();
    }
```

Картинка с результатом:

[image: парадоксальный результат]

[топологическая сортировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Первая ссылка в вашем вопросе - не топологическая сортировка (если быть точным).

Comment: Нашёл сортировку Тарьяна: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0_(1976)

Comment: Видимо у Тарьяна два именных алгоритма. Почему нет?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - да, спасибо, я тоже уже нашел эту статью с понятным объяснением алгоритма

Comment: Интересно, что всегда встречал его как Таржана...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы что-то не то делаете, заполняя `g` - это не список рёбер, а списки смежности, т.е. `g[i]` содержит вектор с номерами вершин, в которые есть дуги из i-й вершины. Поменяйте два раза `[8]` на `[5]` и

```
g[0] = { 1, 2, 3};
g[1] = { 3 };
g[2] = { 3, 4 };
g[3] = { 4 };
g[4] = { };
```

Рeзультат:

```
0 2 1 3 4
```

Comment: Семен семеныч! Огромное спасибо! Это еще раз доказывает, как легко сделать сайт с "так себе" (я сильно смягчил выражения) контентом, и как тяжело - с понятным контентом. О том, что такое g[] -= на исходной странице нет ни слова. А я гадаю - почему рёбра задаются не парами чисел, а целыми vector<int>...

Comment: @S.H. В [одной из статей того сайта](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/connected_components) по элементарным алг. на графах упоминается `Мы считаем, что граф задан списками смежности, т.е. g[i] содержит список вершин, в которые есть рёбра из вершины i`, но не в идущих по логике ранее описаниях dfs и bfs. Автор, видимо, привык подразумевать это, и не брал в голову, что в отдельно взятой статье надо бы пояснить. В общем-то, по смыслу использования понятно, что это списки смежности,  если есть некий опыт общения с графами.

Comment: Согласен, когда пару недель занимаешься графами - то как то такое у тебя в голове закрепляется, когда же после рабочего дня пытаешься за пару часов въехать в тему - ну, 50 на 50, что догадаешься...